# Setting datagridviewimagecolumn image layout

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, datagridview

How can I set the layout style of an image cell or entire image column's image size to stretched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried:

```
dataGridViewImageColumn.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;
```

?